# WPF derived Shape triggering redraw on property change

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes, redraw

I have a circular progress bar, which I have implemented as a class derived from `Shape`. I added `DependencyProperties` for all my properties that I need to bind. Property `Value` represents the progress. I overrided `DefiningGeometry`.

Now I want to get the progress bar to reflect to change when `Value` changes. My current approach is to register a `PropertyChangedCallback` on the `DepencencyProperties` that fires `shape.InvalidateVisual()`.

This works fine, unless I have a `Tooltip` over my progress bar. A `Timer` increments `Value`, and the the `Tooltip` **flickers** once.

**What would be the right way to get the shape updated?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the flicker was triggered by an extended `ObservableCollection` that would would generate a `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` event that triggered a redraw of all items in the `ItemsControl` containing the `Shapes`.

Following [How to properly refresh a custom shape in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458802/how-to-properly-refresh-a-custom-shape-in-wp) I improved my `DepependecyProperty` to:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Start",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(CircleSegment),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                0.0,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    /// <summary>
    /// Start of the Segment. 0 is top (12 o'clock), 0.25 is right (3 o'clock), 0.25 is bottom (6 o'clock), 0.75 is left (9 o'clock).
    /// Painting is always Clockwise from Start to End.
    /// </summary>
    [TypeConverter(typeof(LengthConverter))]
    public double Start
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(StartProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartProperty, value); }
    }
```